# Identifying Specific Sounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-audio

I am trying to identify a specific sound - a baseball being hit with a bat. I have measured the hertz of a number of recordings of a ball being hit and established a relatively reliable hertz range for the hits. I was hoping to use the hertz range within which the recorded sounds fall to identify a hit recorded by the microphone. This generally works well, but certain sounds like a whistle do fall within the same range. How can I identify specific sounds more reliably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to frequency, your program could evaluate the amplitude (envelope) over time. If a sound is one second, then it would not qualify. If its attack is too slow, it would not qualify.

Beyond the base frequency, you can detect/match fluctuation to frequency as well as timbre/harmonics.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I am a total noob when it comes to audio analysis. Could you perhaps give me some idea on how to "detect/match fluctuation to frequency as well as timbre/harmonics"?

Comment: @RunLoop if you're a noob, this isn't simple. if you can match frequencies, you're off to a good start! a) well, that frequency may vary over time. rather than matching one frequency, evaluate how that fundamental frequency varies over time. e.g. if the signal falls sharply and the source you want to match rises or is steady, then it would not match.

Comment: @RunLoop b) most natural sounds have harmonic (and inharmonic) overtones which you can evaluate. these would be frequencies which occur at the same time, but have overtones with different weights and typically different frequencies. if viewed in a spectrogram, the distribution of a piano and a violin playing the same  note would be different. also, a whistle would have a very different distribution of strengths and frequencies from the baseball.

Comment: thank you very much. Do you have any idea how I can get these distributions in iOS? I am currently using the FMOD framework for the frequency analysis.

Comment: @RunLoop sorry, idk about FMOD. i am guessing you already have the signal in an FFT for frequency detection. so just evaluate amplitudes of other frequencies (over time would also be good), starting with harmonic overtones. those are multiples of the fundamental frequency. so if the fundamental were 1kHz, then check the amp of 2kHz, 3kHz, and so on. for the baseball, I would also scan for that sharp transient and fast decay for early elimination.

Comment: @RunLoop also, harmonics can be tough to match -- wood bat? aluminum bat? baseball? softball? frequency response of microphone used and proximity? post-processing? crowd noises? they can all make accurate matching difficult.

Comment: Thanks for all your help :) If I can figure out how to do the distribution analysis on my own I'll mark your answer as accepted, but in the mean time I hope someone will post some code help/example.

Comment: I have done some further testing. One thing which confuses me is that the hertz for the same sound varies according to the distance of the sound from the microphone. I thought hertz and decibel were 2 independent properties - am I wrong, or is the code producing the hertz measurements?

Comment: @RunLoop you probably see that the *distribution* of frequencies varies -- and not the pitch. let's say you have 2 mics recording the same hit. a directional mic off axis vs on axis, or at different distances will have different frequency distributions. this may have to do with phase cancellation/construction and diffusion or proximity. it may also be complicated by post-processing, depending on whether your signal is (or has been) sent through these effects or not.

Comment: @RunLoop by frequency distribution, i meant the amplitudes of the frequencies would change -- not the frequencies themselves (say you have used 2 mics to record the same hit). of course, two different hits may have variance in pitch or frequency distribution. you're welcome.